# Automatically calculate the sum of input values with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, codeigniter, input

I need some help in calculating the sum of the numbers a user has entered, and display it automatically. When the user delete one number the sum should also auto calculate.

```js
$('.col-lg-1').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.col-lg-1').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $('#result').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label>TEST 1 </label>

  <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $section_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $session_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="<?php echo $class_id; ?>">
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca1" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="t2">
  <label>TEST 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca2" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="assg">
  <label>TEST 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca3" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <output id="result"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: `.col-lg-1` is a DIV - you're attaching a change event and trying to get `this.value` from a DIV...

Comment: Changing something in an input does, in fact, trigger a change event in the parent div because it bubbles up. What doesn't work is `$(this).val()` because a div has no value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there. You are targeting `'.col-lg-1'` which are divs, not inputs. You need to target the inputs in order to read their values.

```js
const $inputs = $('input[type="number"]')

$inputs.change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $('#result').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label>TEST 1 </label>

  <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $section_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $session_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="<?php echo $class_id; ?>">
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca1" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="t2">
  <label>TEST 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca2" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="assg">
  <label>TEST 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca3" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <output id="result"></output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.col-lg-1` is a **DIV** - you're attaching a change event and trying to get `this.value` from a DIV which will not work.

Instead, cache your inputs and (on `"input"` event) [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) their values into an integer:

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $inp = $(".input-sm"); //PS: Use a more specific selector than this one
  const $res = $("#result");

  $inp.on("input", () => {
    const total = $inp.get().reduce((acc, el) => (acc += parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0), 0);
    $res.text(total);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div>
<label>TEST 1 </label>
<input type="number" name="mt_ca1" class="inp form-control input-sm rounded-0" required value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="t2">
  <label>TEST 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca2" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1" id="assg">
  <label>TEST 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="mt_ca3" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" required value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <output id="result"></output>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

your each element is number type and have same classes 'form-control', 'input-sm', & 'rounded-0'.
so either

```
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $('#result').html(total);
});
```

or

```
$('.rounded-0').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.rounded-0').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $('#result').html(total);
});
```

can be used.

Comment: what's wrong with this answer to down vote ?? :( @MissJargo